# Bootstrap 4 tooltip in wrong position

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and have compiled a copy of the CSS from the Sass files. Using Ruby Sass 3.7.4

I've removed some parts of the Sass, but don't think there are dependencies that have any affect on how Tooltips work: `code`, `card`, `badge`, `jumbotron`, `progress`, `carousel`.

The markup is as simple as this:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>
```

And it renders like this (incorrectly):

[image]

I've removed all of my own CSS so it's literally the compiled Bootstrap 4 CSS.

I've also included `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` and `jquery-3.2.1.min.js`

I'm not sure why this is happening because the examples given in the docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#examples work as I'd expect.

The js to initialise the Tooltips is in a js file that's present on page load:

```
$(function () { 
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

Anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: add working example like https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

This works fine...
May be, Something wrong with your CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that is a missing css property. Using something like this for the test:

```
.tooltip{
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
```